# Javascript giving string not function on line 2 3

Tags: javascript, linker, web

I am trying to link the javascript to my html file but it is giving me Unknown error String is not a function! Could somebody please tell me what is wrong!!!
Also I do not want the validation to take place on submission but on click, I mean every time I press tab. Is the following code correct?

```
function validate()
{
    var name=document.forms[0].name.value();
    var fac= document.forms[0].fac.value();
    var erp= document.forms[0].erp.value();
    var contact=document.forms[0].contact.value();
    var studh=document.forms[0].studh.value();
    var sc=document.forms[0].sc.value();
    var reg=document.forms[0].reg.value();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all:

```
.value();
```

to:

```
.value;
```

Because `value` is an attribute and not a function.

Comment: Thanks I changed it, now it showing one more error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null on the following code:if(!name.match(letters))

Answer (score 0):

`.value` is an attribute, not a function. If there is `Harshita Pathak` in your `name` field, `document.forms[0].name.value` is a string `"Harshita Pathak"`. You are trying to call `"Harshita Pathak"` as if it was a function when you append `()`.